# Does a splitter still reduce signal if only 1 of its ports is used?

Tags: current, signal, signal-theory

I'm using a Wilson Electronics signal amplification system to try to get phone signal in my house. I'm going to attempt using a coaxial splitter like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0077QMDGY) to split the amplified signal to multiple indoor antennas for broadcasting to multiple parts of the house, since the house is large and has thick stone walls that block signal very effectively.

However, I haven't ordered the second indoor antenna yet. I only have one right now.

What I'm wondering is, once the splitter arrives and I've added it into the system, will I be able to tell immediately if there's a significant signal drop across the splitter, or will it not be apparent until I've bought the second antenna and attached it as well?

To rephrase, if only one port on the splitter is used, is the signal drop to that one port the same as when all four ports are used? Is it the splitter itself which diminishes the signal, or is it the extra devices attached to it drawing part of the voltage away?

Comment: What do you connect to the other port? Nothing? Then the signal will reflect from the port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To rephrase, if only one port on the splitter is used, is the signal drop to that one port the same as when all four ports are used?*

You should not be using it that way! This splitter/filter has no in put for power so it is a completely **passive** device meaning, the power which comes out **must** be smaller than the power which goes in. Ideally all signal power that feeds into it should get out but that's not going to happen, there will **always** be some signal loss, no matter what.

It is also designed to **only** split that power properly (as intended) when **all** outputs have a connection to a device with an antenna input.

If you leave one or more outputs open then the signal will **reflect** (as it cannot go anywhere, it goes back) and that **disturbs** the signal on all outputs. This doesn't cause any damage as the signals are very low in power. But you might suffer from ghost images on a TV or general bad reception, so be aware of that! But as a temporary solution until you connect everything properly, it is OK.

*Is it the splitter itself which diminishes the signal, or is it the extra devices attached to it drawing part of the voltage away?*

As I mention above, the splitter cannot amplify the signal so what power comes in is devided between **all** outputs. "Drawing voltage away" does not happen and is not the issue. The splitter must be connected properly and only then will it divide the signal equally.

So connecting only one port to a TV and leaving the rest open will actually result in the **worst** signal at the TV. You get the best signal with no splitter (cable straight into TV). Using the splitter properly (all ports in use) is the middle solution, you would get a decent signal everywhere provided that the signal going into the splitter is strong enough.

**Sidenote 1:**

There's the issue of **characteristic impedance**.

My bet is that the splitter you choose is designed for **75 ohms** systems like TVs radios and cable modems. My bet is also that your 4G amplifier has a **50 ohms** system as that is what is commonly used for cell phones and nearly anything related to it. The fact that the splitter does not mention 50 Ohms or 75 Ohms worries me.

Like using the splitter in the wrong way, the 50 Ohms vs 75 Ohms will not damage anything physically but it will harm the signals such that things are unlikely to work like you want. My bet is that the money you're spending on this will be wasted. You should stick with the products that the 4G extender's manufacturer sells as that is designed to work together. If they don't sell what you need then you're out of luck.

**Sidenote 2:**

Do realize that what you're trying to do might not work (properly). You have to be sure that the 4G (?) signals you're trying to distribute might not be in the supported frequency range of this splitter. It would be helpful to know which frequency band you are using. I know that 850 MHz is a band used for 4 G but also 1700 MHz up to 1900 MHz is used. And even though the splitter optimistically mentions 2500 MHz, in practice these cheap devices have quite poor performance at such a high frequencies.

Then there's the cables you will be using. Even at 800 MHz a decent cable will attenuate the signal, at 1700 MHz and higher signal losses can be very bad. Use the best quality (lowest loss) cable you can afford.

So if you're using 4G at 850 MHz, then what you intend to do might work. At the higher frequency bands maybe it will not work so well or not work at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for this very detailed answer! You're right about 50 vs 75 ohms. I already made the mistake of purchasing 100ft of 75ohm cable and the signal loss was bad. Replaced it with 50ohm cable and that works great. It is indeed a 50ohm system.

Comment: Do you think [this splitter](https://www.wilsonamplifiers.com/6db-4-way-splitter-for-700-2700mhz-50ohm-859981/) from the amplifier manufacturer is actually different? It seemed to me that it was nearly the same thing yet so much more expensive. I can afford it fine but thought it was just a scam with no actual extra value since it seems to also be passive. Only difference is it specifies 50ohms.

Comment: *Do you think this splitter is actually different?* **Oh yes!!!** Very different. If only for the fact that it states that it is for 50 Ohms. Sure, even if you would open them and look inside the "cheap" one and the "expensive" one might look similar. But the values of the components inside will be different and that will make or break the performance. The cheap one is for 75 ohms and that's why it is cheap as they're mass produced and performance isn't that critical.

Answer (score 1):

The splitter does not have a datasheet so it is impossible to know what topology is used inside that specific item. When used properly (with terminators)  the attenuation of a typical passive splitter is fixed.

The `insertion loss` is associated with the device itself, and is a decrease in power delivered to the output due to the impedance network inside a typical passive splitter.

Attenuation would depend on the connected load, however, you should be terminating unused ports with the proper termination resistance. When using the appropriate terminators the attenuation is fixed, nominally -6dB for a typical passive 4-port splitter.

Unterminated, unbalanced, or shorted connections will cause reflections, and the effective attenuation depends on the interference of these reflections in the splitter.